# Ubuntu: how to make apt-get/synaptic work for own application

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, packaging

We are developing a (closed-source) Java application and think about possibilities to update the software automatically on the user's machines. Fortunately, for nearly all Linux systems there exist package managers. We don't think it would be useful to add our application to the common repositories for several reasons, but how to create an own one, manage it and tell the user's machines to poll and update from that?

Comment: The lowest hanging fruit here is Java Web Start for all platforms.  Care to share what you need that JWS cannot provide?

Comment: JWS is no solution for several reasons. One is, that it requires an installed Java.

Answer (score 3):

For packaging a application see the [Debian Maintainers Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/). To distribute the packages you need to set up your own package-repository this can be done using the `dpkg-scanpackages` or the `reprepro` tool. A short introduction to this can be found [in this blog post](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286). To simplify adding a new build package to the repo, have a look at the `dupload` tool.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Java/Packaging page](http://wiki.debian.org/Java/Packaging) on the Debian wiki.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Host a repository](http://www.arsgeek.com/2007/02/14/how-to-set-up-your-own-local-repositories-with-apt-mirror/)  on a web-server locally.
2. Package your software as [theomega](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377652/ubuntu-how-to-make-apt-get-synaptic-work-for-own-application#answer-3377658) stated.
3. Add your software to repository.

Comment: I think apt-mirror is not ment to build a new repo but instead to mirror (hence the name) a existing repo, but I might be wrong.